# how to use inno setup for a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, inno-setup

Question 1449994 addressed my question, but I dont see where to put the sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        string parameter = string.Concat(args);
        switch (parameter)
        {
            case "--install":
                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                break;
            case "--uninstall":
                ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/u", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location });
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new WindowsService());
    }
}
```

a service application doesnt have a Main method, so where does this code go? I tried putting it before OnStart, but it would not build.

Comment: Could you format your code as code, with the code button on the SO editor please? No one will help you if that can't read this.

Comment: What makes you say that a Windows Service doesn't have a `Main` method? Every one that I've ever seen has.

Comment: You want to run a Setup from you service or to use InnoSetup to install your service?